# Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation assembly not loading

Tags: solr, upgrade

I'm upgrading my Sitecore 8.1 Visual Studio project to use Sitecore 8.2, and I've made quite a bit of progress. I've switched to SOLR, updated Glass Mapper, and replaced out my DLL references to use the Sitecore supplied NuGet package manager. The issue that I've hit now I believe is related somehow to the new SOLR implementation that doesn't use DI. I am getting the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   could not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrNetIntegration.IntegrationHelper.IsSolrConfigured()
>   +0    Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeSolrProvider.Process(PipelineArgs
>   args) +28    (Object , Object[] ) +71
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +484
>   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName,
>   PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +22
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +259
>   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +704
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +618
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +402
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +343
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +112    System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +712
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1055.0

I've tried several things, including changing the dependentAssembly to point to the correct publicKeyToken (which is `59d6d24383174ac4` and not `31bf3856ad364e35` as the error message suggests). I'd appreciate any help that you all can provide. Thanks!

Comment: I added to my answer the issue with SOLR. There's no longer a need to use the SOLR Support DLL'S in 8.2.

Comment: Have you tried enabling assembly binding log to see which assembly is causing problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to make sure that you update all your projects to .NET 4.5.2+ in the Project Properties Screen. You'll need to do this for every project in the solution.

You will also want to make sure the VS Extention for Microsoft Practices is updated.

Also, do not use the SOLR Support Packages DLL. SOLR is now natively in the Sitecore dll's.  Just enable the 8.2 Solr configs.

Comment: Your last statement about not using the SOLR Support packages DLLs really was the key for me. I had setup a sandbox without those DLLs and everything was working, so I ended up comparing the DLLs in my bin folder to those from a clean install, and was able to find the problem files.